# How to fix a keyboard layout on each Windows 10 computer?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, language, microsoft-account

I use Windows 10 with the same Microsoft account on 3 different computers, each one with a different physical keyboard layout: ITA, UK, DE.

In "Control panel - Clock and International settings - Language" I have ITA as display language with ITA/DE/UK keyboard layouts, followed by ENG(US) with only UK layout.

In the same window I opened "Advanced settings" where I set an override (second drop-down list) to the default ("the first one on the list") language/keyboard: that would be ITA/ITA, while I want (on this computer) ITA/DE.

However, when now I log in in the other computers, I get ITA/DE there as well, while each computer should have a different one, being the physical keyboards different: ITA/DE here, ITA/UK on the second one and ITA/ITA on the third one.

If I change one, they all change. And if I don't apply the override, the issue seems to be the same.

Basically the last used language AND keyboard settings are stored on the cloud and applied wherever I log in.

How to set Windows 10 to remember, PER computer, the last used language/keyboard layout settings, without having that setting follow me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to modify that within the synchronization settings on each machine:

1. Press <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Type `Sync your settings` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. In the subsequent window, switch `Language preferences` to **Off**

   [image: Sync your settings]

Comment: Never noticed that. It should work.